# How does a subshell's executed lines get printed to the main shell without running the source command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

Let's say I have an executable shell script called foo.sh. Inside it is a simple echo "Hello World". From my understanding, when I run this via ./foo.sh, a subshell is invoked which executes the echo "Hello World" line.

Why, then, do I see the output of the echo command in my main shell/terminal? I would think you'd have to do a "source ./foo.sh" instead of the simple "./foo.sh" to see the output in your current shell.

Can any of you help clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard output is **inherited**. Quoting from [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment):

> **Command Execution Environment**
>
> When a simple command other than a builtin or shell function is to be
> executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment that
> consists of the following. Unless otherwise noted, the values are
> **inherited** from the shell.
>
> - the shell’s open files, plus any modifications and additions specified by redirections to the command
> - ...